# how the setup Node Red log file on linux?

Tags: node-red

I'm using a linux device, that runs node-red. And I've been looking for the log file of node red without any success, based on node-red page the `setting.js` file is defining where to find it:

```
    // Configure the logging output
    logging: {
        // Only console logging is currently supported
        console: {
            // Level of logging to be recorded. Options are:
            // fatal - only those errors which make the application unusable should be recorded
            // error - record errors which are deemed fatal for a particular request + fatal errors
            // warn - record problems which are non fatal + errors + fatal errors
            // info - record information about the general running of the application + warn + error + fatal errors
            // debug - record information which is more verbose than info + info + warn + error + fatal errors
            // trace - record very detailed logging + debug + info + warn + error + fatal errors
            // off - turn off all logging (doesn't affect metrics or audit)
            level: "info",
            // Whether or not to include metric events in the log output
            metrics: false,
            // Whether or not to include audit events in the log output
            audit: false
        }
    }
}
```

So based on that, I still don't where the file is, and if I can setup a location of the logging. 
Does anyone has a hint how to solve this?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As described in the Node-RED [docs](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/logging), Node-RED does not write a log file by default, it logs to stderr on the console where it was started.

If you are running Node-RED using the systemd service file so it runs on start up then you can use the `node-red-log` command to tail the output. The log is written to the `journald` with the tag `nodered` or to `/var/log/node-red.log` on systems without journald